# radscheduler rowheight of appointment not changing

Tags: asp.net, telerik, appointment, row-height, radscheduler

I have a radscheduler on my page. I want to adjust the height of the appointment. I played with the rowheight parameter and adaptiverowheight parameter but nothing seems to change.

```
  <telerik:RadScheduler ID="radScheduler" runat="server" OnLoad="radScheduler_Load" SelectedView="MonthView"
                DataKeyField="AppointmentID" DataSubjectField="AppointmentInformation" DataStartField="BeginningDayDate" DataEndField="EndingDayDate" Height="700px"
                OnAppointmentCreated="radScheduler_AppointmentCreated" OnAppointmentInsert="radScheduler_AppointmentInsert" OnAppointmentUpdate="radScheduler_AppointmentUpdate" 
                OnAppointmentDelete="radScheduler_AppointmentDelete" Font-Bold="true" ShowHeader="true" OnClientAppointmentClick="OnClientAptClick" 
                OnClientAppointmentEditing="OnClientAptEditing" 
                OnAppointmentClick="radScheduler_AppointmentClick" AllowInsert="false" RowHeight="10px" AppointmentStyleMode="Default">
<MonthView HeaderDateFormat="MMMM yyyy" VisibleAppointmentsPerDay="30" AdaptiveRowHeight="false"  />
```

Why is this not changing? What am i missing?If you need more info,please ask.Thanks.
The telerik version is : 2013.1.417.40

Answer (score 0):

Try the dyanmic, MonthView-only, code provided by Telerik, here: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/scheduler/radscheduler-rowheight-and-timelineview.aspx